# cannot reset iOS simulator - Could not reset simulator. Leaving as is. Error: Command failed: // stderr

Tags: ios-simulator, reset, xcode6.1

I'm using Xcode 6.1, iPhone 6 simulator for my Appium automation tests.

I'm having a trouble of reset iOS simulator. The first time after reboot using simulator is always fine. But if I quit the simulator, and tried to use it again (both manually and load using Appium tool), I'll keep getting blackscreen for simulator. I got the following info from my automation log 'Could not reset simulator. Leaving as is. Error: Command failed:  // stderr'

I've tried the 'Reset Content and Settings' from simulator, it would not help. I still getting the black screen. and I've also tried to kill the simulator from command line using 'killall SimulatorBridge', still not work.

The only way that I could get this working is - reboot my laptop... this gives me a big pain. I'm thinking if reboot could help, there must be some process that I could kill to reset it? Anyone could kindly give me some help here? Many thanks!